# Условие выполнения команды WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Использую Prism. Во VM описываю свойство

```
private Employee _dgSelectedItem;
public Employee DgSelectedItem
{
    get => _dgSelectedItem;
    set
    {
        _dgSelectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DgSelectedItem));
    }
}
```

Объявляю команду:

```
public DelegateCommand OpenCommand { get; }
```

и соответственно ее описание в конструкторе

```
OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
        //какое-то действие
    }, () => DgSelectedItem != null);
```

Собственно вопрос про булевское условие команды. DgSelectedItem меняется при клике на какую либо строку datagrid, но кнопка остается неактивной. Подскажите, что я делю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам при обновлении `DgSelectedItem` надо вызывать `DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`:

```
public Employee DgSelectedItem
{
    get => _dgSelectedItem;
    set
    {
        _dgSelectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DgSelectedItem));
        OpenCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

т. к. команда сама по себе никак не может догадаться, что изменились условия запуска.